# @JsonAppend virtual property – does ObjectReader honor it?

Tags: jackson-databind

There's documentation on how to use `@JsonAppend` to add a virtual property to a POJO when serializing it to JSON. However, no Javadoc or article says anything about deserialization. Suppose we add a "schemaVersion" property to an object:

```
@JsonAppend(attrs = { @JsonAppend.Attr(value = "schemaVersion") })
public static class MixinWithVersion {}
```

How do we read objects that have that property set? I'm getting `UnrecognizedPropertyException` and wondering if it's even possible to read back in an object with an added property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `@JsonIgnoreProperties` solves the problem on deserialization:

```
@JsonAppend(attrs = { @JsonAppend.Attr(value = "schemaVersion") })
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "schemaVersion" })
public static class MixinWithVersion {}
```